# could not find a version that satisfies the requirement context.viewer (from context)

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install context module in python with: `pip install context`
but I encounter this error :

```
 ERROR : could not find a version that satisfies the requirement context.viewer (from context)
 ERROR : no matching distribution found for context.viewer
```

I tried all the solutions mentioned on the site but I did not get any results.

Comment: there are two context module available in python please post question in detail.

Comment: i've been having problems running a code at (github.com/antoineBarbez/SMAD ) , I came across this line in code : from context import ROOT_DIR when i run code,I encounter this error : no module named 'context'

Answer (score 2):

[`context`](https://pypi.org/project/context/) requires [`context.api`](https://pypi.org/project/context.api/) and [`context.viewer`](https://pypi.org/project/context.viewer/); the former is available but latter isn't.

Both available modules are at version 0.0, released in 2012. Bottom line: the module is abandoned and broken, forget about it.

Are you sure you really need this module and not another one? The word "context" is rather heavily overloaded in programming…

Comment: i've been having problems running a code at (https://github.com/antoineBarbez/SMAD ) ,
I came across this line in code : from context import ROOT_DIR
when i run code,I encounter this error : no module named 'context'

Comment: I see `context.py` in the root of the repository. I'm sure it's the module to be imported.

Comment: I can't import this...Thank you so much for taking the time to review it

Comment: The repository isn't `pip`-installable so you need to set `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path` pointing to your cloned directory. Then `import context` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Good evening,
I could install context in pycharm and also in terminal in my PC.
Upgrade pip, setuptools, wheel:

python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

apt-get install python3-venv

To get into venv mode:

source /home/vb1/PycharmProjects/sub-vb1.py/venv/bin/activate

pip install context.api

Alternatively create venv (virtual environment) there are 3 ways:
https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/#optionally-create-a-virtual-environment

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

#All in all, its easiest way is to use pycharm:

- inside that install package "context.api"
- then in Project setting -> Project structure -> set your project path as RED (Exclude) and set VENV as blue (Source). It activate venv for your project.

I have some code examples in my github page too:

https://github.com/amin-tayebi/Smart-Irrigation-Precision-Agriculture-using-Lorawan/tree/main/API

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to render contexts (including navigation) for wxPython, PyGame, and GLUT, as well as a partial context for Tkinter, then use this.

```
pip install OpenGLContext
```

Comment: `OpenGLContext` has a module `conext` but it's a module of the package, it cannot be imported as just `context`. It also doesn't have a subpackage `context.viewer`.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying import context directly from sqlalchemy try sqlalchemy.orm

Comment: What makes you think this has anything to do with SQLAlchemy?